# Grails 3.2.0.M1 Template not found for name

Tags: grails, gson, grails3

In my domain class **com.example.users.User** I added transient field carnets:

```
class User implements Serializable {
    ...
    def carnets

    static transients = ['springSecurityService', 'carnets']
    ...
}
```

and in my gson view **user/_user.gson** I'd like to render it:

```
import com.example.users.User

model {
    User user
}

json g.render(user, [excludes:['password', 'deleted', 'enabled', 'accountExpired', 'accountLocked', 'passwordExpired', 'authorities']]) {
    //"carnets" g.render(template:"/carnet/index", collection: user.carnets, var:'carnets')
    "carnets" tmpl.'/carnet/index'(user.carnets)
}
```

but I've received:

> Caused by: grails.views.ViewRenderException: Error rendering view: Template not found for name /carnet/index

Carnet's views gson files were autogenerated and works fine when executed from CarnetController.

What am I missing?

Comment: Step one should obviously be to upgrade to a newer release than the first milestone release of the major version you're using, in this case 3.2.2

Comment: I tried it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441814/second-level-expand-in-gson/40462611#40462611 but thanks for a hint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my use case (Grails 3.3.0), I had to change the template path from:
`tmpl.'message/message'`
to:
`tmpl.'/message/message'`
(added leading slash).

Using the `../` syntax worked in development, but caused an error for me when deploying the WAR file to Tomcat. See: [https://github.com/grails/grails-views/issues/140]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a relative path to the template from the current `.gson` file, unfortunately. I would imagine that that option would be an relative path from the `views` folder, but it's apparently not the case.

Let's assume your `views` folder structure is as follows:

```
views/
    carnet/
         _index.gson
    user/
        _user.gson
```

In this case, your `_user.gson` file needs to be as follows:

```
import com.example.users.User

model {
    User user
}

json g.render(user, [excludes:['password', 'deleted', 'enabled', 'accountExpired', 'accountLocked', 'passwordExpired', 'authorities']]) {
    "carnets" tmpl.'../carnet/index'(user.carnets)
}
```

TL;DR change `tmpl.'/carnet/index'` to `tmpl.'../carnet/index'`. :)