# Second level expand in gson

Tags: grails, gson, grails3

I'm using Grails 3.2.2 and org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.1.1 and in my section gson I'd like to expand all users and their carnets. I tried:

```
import com.example.sections.Section

model {
    Section section
}

json g.render(section, [excludes:['archived', 'deleted'], expand:['clients', 'clients.carnets']]){
}
```

but it only expands clients in result json. how  can I do that?
btw carnets in Client domain class are transient. Is it possible to add transient variables to result gson? If so - how?

Comment: Not as of version 1.1, but seems like a reasonable thing to want to do. Please report and issue https://github.com/grails/grails-views/issues